# Drop down menus hover, but sub menus don't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I've tried searching for this but just can't find the right coding. Can someone help?
This is my site currently in test mode : http://www.rockclick.co.uk/wiss/index.htm .
As you can see I have hoverable menus. But my sub menus under the "Galleries" hover menu don't hover I have to click on them in my PC browser (google chrome). On my iphone the submenus aren't even clickable. (I've added a script to fix the hover bug for IOS).
I'm very reluctant to re-write the whole thing again. Is there an easy fix to just make my sub menus hoverable??
I'm very much a novice at this stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  console.log(e);
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  console.log(target);
  if (target.parentElement.className.indexOf('has-submenu') > -1) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('open');
  }
}, false);

<!----------------ios-hover-fix----------->
(function(l){var i,s={touchend:function(){}};for(i in s)l.addEventListener(i,s)})(document); // sticky hover fix in iOS
```

```css
<style>
#menu {background: #F9F3DB; color: #6D6C6B; height: 35px; border-bottom: 0px solid #6D6C6B}
#menu ul,
#menu li {margin: 0 0; padding: 0 0; list-style: none}
#menu ul {height: 35px}
#menu li {float: left; display: inline; position: relative; font: bold 12px Arial; text-shadow: 0 0px 0 #6D6C6B; border-right: 0px solid #444;
  border-left: 0px solid #111; text-transform: uppercase}

#menu li:first-child {border-left: none}
#menu a {display: block; line-height: 35px; padding: 0 14px; text-decoration: none; color: #6D6C6B;}
#menu li:hover > a,
#menu li a:hover {background: #F9F3DB}
#menu input { display: none; margin: 0 0; padding: 0 0; width: 80px; height: 35px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer}
#menu label {font: bold 30px Arial; display: none; width: 35px; height: 36px; line-height: 36px; text-align: center}
#menu label span {font-size: 12px; position: absolute; left: 35px}
#menu ul.menus {height: auto; width: auto; background: #F9F3DB; position: absolute; z-index: 99; display: none; border: 0;}
#menu ul.menus li {display: block; width: 100%; font: 12px Arial; text-transform: none;}
#menu li:hover ul.menus {display: block}
#menu a.home {background: #c00;}
#menu a.prett {padding: 0 27px 0 14px}
#menu a.prett::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 5px 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #6D6C6B transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 9px}

#menu a.prett.open::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #6D6C6B transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 9px}

#menu ul.menus a:hover {background: #F9F3DB;}
#menu ul.menus .submenu {display: none; position: absolute; left: 100px; background: #F9F3DB; top: 0; width: 150px;}
#menu ul.menus .submenu li {background: #F9F3DB;}
#menu ul.menus .has-submenu a.open ~ .submenu {display: block;}

</style>
```

```html
<!------------NAVIGATION-BAR------>
<body>
<nav>
  <ul id='menu'>
     <li><a class='prett' href='#' title='Galleries'>Galleries</a>
  <ul class='menus'>
 <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' title='Photos'>Photos</a>
  <ul class='submenu'>       
        <li><a href="gallery 2017.htm" target="iframe">2017</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery 2016.htm" target="iframe">2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery 2015.htm" target="iframe">2015</a></li>
 </ul></li>
     
 <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' title='Archives'>Media</a>
  <ul class='submenu'>       
        <li><a href="media.htm" target="iframe">Press Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="archive media.htm" target="iframe">Archived Press</a></li>
        </ul></li>

    <li><a href="team photos.htm" target="iframe" title='Team Photos'>Team Photos</a></li>
 <li><a href="videos.htm" target="iframe" title='Videos'>Videos</a></li>

 </ul></li> 
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a MINIMAL example of the problem.

Comment: Jo, you might want to check out [Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com). This is a great resource that simplifies things for you and is easily customized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider declaring an additional `:hover` state rule for nested submenu elements, this can be chained onto the existing submenu `:hover` state rule, e.g:

```
#menu li:hover ul.menus, #menu li.has-submenu:hover ul.submenu {
    display: block;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  console.log(e);
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  console.log(target);
  if (target.parentElement.className.indexOf('has-submenu') > -1) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('open');
  }
}, false);

<!----------------ios-hover-fix----------->
(function(l) {
  var i, s = {
    touchend: function() {}
  };
  for (i in s) l.addEventListener(i, s)
})(document); // sticky hover fix in iOS
```

```css
#menu {
  background: #F9F3DB;
  color: #6D6C6B;
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #6D6C6B
}

#menu ul,
#menu li {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none
}

#menu ul {
  height: 35px
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font: bold 12px Arial;
  text-shadow: 0 0px 0 #6D6C6B;
  border-right: 0px solid #444;
  border-left: 0px solid #111;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

#menu li:first-child {
  border-left: none
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6D6C6B;
}

#menu li:hover>a,
#menu li a:hover {
  background: #F9F3DB
}

#menu input {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

#menu label {
  font: bold 30px Arial;
  display: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center
}

#menu label span {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px
}

#menu ul.menus {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background: #F9F3DB;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
  border: 0;
}

#menu ul.menus li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font: 12px Arial;
  text-transform: none;
}

#menu li:hover ul.menus, #menu li.has-submenu:hover ul.submenu {
  display: block
}

#menu a.home {
  background: #c00;
}

#menu a.prett {
  padding: 0 27px 0 14px
}

#menu a.prett::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 5px 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #6D6C6B transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 9px
}

#menu a.prett.open::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #6D6C6B transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 9px
}

#menu ul.menus a:hover {
  background: #F9F3DB;
}

#menu ul.menus .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  background: #F9F3DB;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

#menu ul.menus .submenu li {
  background: #F9F3DB;
}

#menu ul.menus .has-submenu a.open~.submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!------------NAVIGATION-BAR------>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul id='menu'>
      <li><a href="home.htm" target="iframe">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="news.htm" target="iframe">News</a></li>

      <li><a class='prett' href='#' title='Info'>Information</a>
        <ul class='menus'>
          <li><a href='about us.htm' title='About Us' target="iframe">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href='stats.htm' title='committee' target="iframe">Statistics</a></li>
          <li><a href='docs.htm' title='documents downloads' target="iframe">Downloads</a></li>
          <li><a href='sponsorship.htm' title='Sponsorship' target="iframe">Sponsorship</a></li>
          <li><a href='calendar.htm' title='Calendar' target="iframe">Race Calendar</a></li>
          <li><a href="results.htm" target="iframe">Race Results</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a class='prett' href='#' title='Info'>Meet The Team</a>
        <ul class='menus'>
          <li><a href='the team.htm' title='the team' target="iframe">The Team</a></li>
          <li><a href='coaches.htm' title='coaches' target="iframe">The Coaches</a></li>
          <li><a href='committee.htm' title='committee' target="iframe">The Committee</a></li>


        </ul>
      </li>


      <li><a class='prett' href='#' title='Galleries'>Galleries</a>
        <ul class='menus'>
          <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' title='Photos'>Photos</a>
            <ul class='submenu'>
              <li><a href="gallery 2017.htm" target="iframe">2017</a></li>
              <li><a href="gallery 2016.htm" target="iframe">2016</a></li>
              <li><a href="gallery 2015.htm" target="iframe">2015</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>


          <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' title='Archives'>Media</a>
            <ul class='submenu'>
              <li><a href="media.htm" target="iframe">Press Reports</a></li>
              <li><a href="archive media.htm" target="iframe">Archived Press</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li><a href="team photos.htm" target="iframe" title='Team Photos'>Team Photos</a></li>
          <li><a href="videos.htm" target="iframe" title='Videos'>Videos</a></li>

          <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' title='Archives'>Archives</a>
            <ul class='submenu'>
              <li><a href="archives 1980s.htm" target="iframe">1980's</a></li>
              <li><a href="archives 1990s.htm" target="iframe">1990's</a></li>
              <li><a href="archives 2000s.htm" target="iframe">2000's</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.htm" target="iframe">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="links.htm" target="iframe">Links</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for this answer - works perfectly . You have saved me so much work. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your CSS code. It should fix it.

`.menus li a:hover ~ .submenu {display: block !important;}`